# AddEventListener: ¿Cómo controlar el evento click en dos elementos, uno dentro de otro?

Tags: javascript, html5

Un div dentro de otro div, y lo que quiero es que al hacer clic en el div interior no ocurra nada, pero al hacer clic en el div exterior, cambie de color el div interior. Se podrán hacer más de un clic. Con **addEventListener** y la propagación en burbuja no se puede controlar bien, cuando se hace clic en el div interior, también se captura el evento en el div exterior, y es lo que no quiero. He probado a borrar la escucha con **removeEventListener** y volver a crear una nueva escucha, pero tampoco funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

```
<body>
    <h1>Eventos</h1>
    <div id="fondo" style="background-color:#ffee30; height: 250px;">
        <div id="element" style="background-color:#df92b9;width: 150px; height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
           var fondo = document.getElementById('fondo');
           var element = document.getElementById('element');

           fondo.addEventListener('click', cambia);
           element.addEventListener('click', nada);

           function cambia(){
                element.style.backgroundColor = '#4cee30';
                alert("cambia");
           }

           function nada(){
                alert("nada");
                fondo.removeEventListener('click', cambia);
                fondo.addEventListener('click', cambia);
           }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:
pasando el `event` del click.

**ejemplo:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
var fondo = document.getElementById('fondo');
var element = document.getElementById('element');

fondo.addEventListener('click', cambia);

function cambia(e) {
    //evita el bundle del click
    e.stopPropagation();
    // e.target devolvera el elemento especifico al que se le dio click
    // e.currentTarget devolvera el elemento al que se le asigno el click osea fondo es igual a this.
    if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#4cee30';
        alert("cambia!");
    }

    // otra opciones
    /*
    
    if (e.target ==  this)
    if (e.target.id == this.id)
    if (e.target == fondo) 
    if (e.target.id == fondo.id) 

    */
}

}
```

```html
    <h1>Eventos</h1>
    <div id="fondo" style="background-color:#ffee30; height: 250px;">
        <div id="element" style="background-color:#df92b9;width: 150px; height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¡ Excelente, funcionó ! 
Gracias.